# Cannot use AssimpNet in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, assimp

I can create a new console application or WinForms application and add the NuGet package for AssimpNet (version 3.3.2), but for some reason when I try to load any 3D file from within a fresh ASP.NET Web API project I get the following exception:

Exception:

```
Error loading unmanaged library from path: Assimp32.dll, see inner exception for details.The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`
```

Inner Exception:

```
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`
```

I have tried compiling my project for AnyCPU, x86, and x64 with the same results. This exception is only thrown when trying to use the library. Other endpoints still work fine, and everything compiles without any warnings. I can consistently reproduce this issue using a brand new ASP.NET Web API project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The full error message and stack trace is:

```
An error has occurred.Error loading unmanaged library from path: Assimp32.dll, see inner exception for details.
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)Assimp.AssimpException   at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibraryWindowsImplementation.NativeLoadLibrary(String path)
   at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibraryImplementation.LoadAssimpLibrary(String path)
   at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary()
   at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.CreatePropertyStore()
   at Assimp.AssimpContext.CreateConfigs()
   at Assimp.AssimpContext.ImportFile(String file, PostProcessSteps postProcessFlags)
   at Assimp.AssimpContext.ImportFile(String file)
   at AssimpTest.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(Int32 id) in c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AssimpTest\AssimpTest\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 21
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()An error has occurred.The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ASP.NET (or IIS, I'm not sure which) looks for unmanaged .dlls somewhere in the PATH for the server. The solution to this locally was to copy Assimp32.dll into the SysWOW64 (yes, the 32 bit library was being used even though the application is being executed as 64-bit).

On Azure (which hosts my production environment) you can create a custom folder for unmanaged libraries either via FTP or Kudu, and then modify the PATH for the app server by following [this guide from Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables).

If you're running AssimpNet in a console or desktop application it should work with the copy of Assimp32.dll that is copied to the \bin folder of your solution. If anyone is able to explain *why* this is not the same for console or desktop applications, I would be very happy to up-vote.